# Html5 media player not embed -- android

Tags: android, html

I am integrating the html5 mediaplayer to my application. i used the below code to embed the mediaplayer to my webview

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>`

I can get only voice, but video is not displayed. Can anyone guide me how to embed the mediaplayer for html5.

Answer (score 0):

You [need](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) call `play` method manually:

```
var videoNode = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
videoNode.addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.play();
},false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but, can you please explain me in breif.

Comment: Find [article](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) for you.